# Sull'uso figurato di "sfrittellare"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> In meno di due minuti, Gheri *sfrittellò* a quel beduino nel deserto tutta la faccenda del fratello. 
>         Che sbaglio! Confidarsi con uno che si credeva un giornalista!

Ho cercato il [significato di "sfrittellare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sfrittellare/) e ho trovato questo:

> **sfrittellare** v. tr. [der. di *frittella*, col pref. s- (nel sign. 5)] (*io sfrittèllo*, ecc.). – Macchiare di unto un indumento: *hai già sfrittellato il vestito nuovo*; più com. nella forma *sfrittellarsi*, con la particella pron. in funzione di dativo, seguita da un compl. oggetto, oppure con valore rifl.: *ti sei sfrittellato la giacca*; *sta’ attento a non sfrittellarti*.

È chiaro che questo non è il significato di "sfrittellare" nel brano sopra citato, ma che si tratta di un senso figurato che più o meno si può capire dal contesto. Potreste spiegarmi qualcosa di più su questo significato figurato di "sfrittellare"? Si usa nel linguaggio comune o è invece qualcosa di inventata dalla scrittrice?

Comment: Direi che significa lo stesso di ["spiattellare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiattellare/). Personalmente mai sentito in quest'accezione, a istinto direi licenza poetica :) magari basata sull'assonanza dei due verbi.

Answer (score 1):

Azzardo una risposta, perché quando si chiede cosa abbia inteso una persona usando in maniera figurata un vocabolo che usualmente non lo è, rispondere estrapolandolo dal contesto è quasi sempre un azzardo.

Credo che il termine sia stato sì usato in senso figurato, ma partendo dall'altra accezione di *"sfrittellare"*, ovvero  da  *"il cucinare frittelle **in grande quantità**"* [[Il Nuovo De Mauro] <sup>(1)</sup>](http://archive.org/stream/nvodizionrio00petr#page/950/mode/2up)  o ***"Far di gran frittelle"*** [[Petrocchi 1887] <sup>(2)</sup>](http://archive.org/stream/nvodizionrio00petr#page/950/mode/2up).

Se conosci l'amore per la cucina e per la mimica tipico degli italiani, potrebbe richiamarti alla memoria il gesto usato per sottolineare la locuzione *"... e ancora, e ancora, e ancora..."*, molto simile a quello usato per girare l'impasto delle frittelle.

In questo caso il suo uso al posto di [spiattellare <sup>(3)</sup>](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiattellare/) andrebbe a sottolineare il perdurare dell'azione e la sua non estemporaneità: non è che ti *"è [scappato <sup>(4)</sup>](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scappare/) di dirlo"*, al contrario lo hai detto ed hai continuato a dirlo come avresti continuato a mischiare l'impasto delle frittelle o a rovesciare cucchiaio dopo cucchiaio l'impasto per fare frittelle *in grande quantità*.

Non ricordo un uso comume come inteso dalla Mastracola, semmai puoi trovare un altro esempio sempre figurato ed in un significato non riportato nei vari vocalbolari (diventare/comportarsi come una frittella) in un libro di una nota comica

> ... mettono uno dentro una teca di serpenti, gli fanno mangiare gli scarafaggi, gli mettono due petardi nelle narici, lo appendono per i piedi e vedono quanto resiste, lo fanno **sfrittellare contro un muro** vestito da ape Maia. Ma siamo impazziti?

<sup>"I dolori del giovane Walter" di Luciana Littizzetto</sup>

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @Hastur, e grazie della risposta!

Comment: @Charo: grazie a te su questa tastiera non ho le lettere accentate... :-) Ps> Ti risulta abbastanza comprensibile? Mi riferisco alla descrizione del gesto.